# Size of Font Awesome discrepancy?

Tags: css, icons, font-awesome, cdn

So I'd like to include Font Awesome in my own SASS dir to prevent unnecessary additional calls on pageload. Weirdly, I've found that when you actually download Font Awesome either via GitHub or the npm package, `font-awesome.min.css` is ~27kb, whereas the CDN version (url below) is 7.4kb.

What is going on here??

CDN:

```
https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.5.0/css/font-awesome.min.css
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it's because if you download it using NPM or Bower, 
it would install other things like: 
- css/ 
- fonts/ 
- less/ 
- scss/

Meanwhile on the CDN, you only include one file, 
Maybe that's why the size is pretty different.

Comment: No, the ACTUAL FILESIZE of font-awesome.min.css is different.